# Confer Session Storage

Tags: php, laravel, session

Very simple question that I can't find the answer for. I'm using [Confer](https://github.com/dazzz1er/confer) in my Laravel app and wish to alter the html that is stored in the session storage for each new message. I've made a few formatting changes to conversation messages in `views\conversation.blade.php` as well as `views\confer.blade.php`, but when a user submits a new message, that message is pushed with the original formatting. I can't for the life of me find where the html formatting is passed into the session so it can be pushed to the client.

Confer's `SessionController.php`

```
namespace DJB\Confer\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;
use Response;

class SessionController extends Controller {

/**
 * Store the conversation list HTML in the session so that it can be retained over page loads
 * 
 * @param  Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Session::put('confer_conversations', $request->input('html'));
    return Response::json(['success' => true]); // required to persist the session
}

/**
 * Update the requested conversations that have yet to blossom with a message
 *
 * This needs to persist over page loads otherwise recipient(s) will not be
 * subscribed to the channel to receive any messages.
 * 
 * @param  Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function update(Request $request)
{
    if (Session::has('confer_requested_conversations'))
    {
        Session::push('confer_requested_conversations', (int)$request->input('conversation_id'));
    } else {
        Session::put('confer_requested_conversations', [(int)$request->input('conversation_id')]);
    }
    return Response::json(['success' => true]); // required to persist the session
}

/**
 * Clear the open chat list and requested list
 * 
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy()
{
    Session::forget('confer_conversations');
    Session::forget('confer_requested_conversations');
    return redirect()->back();
}

}
```

`MessageWasSent`

```
namespace DJB\Confer\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use DJB\Confer\Message;
use DJB\Confer\Confer;
use Push;

class MessageWasSent extends Command {

use InteractsWithQueue;

protected $message;
protected $confer;

public function __construct(Message $message)
{
    $this->message = $message;
    $this->confer = new Confer();
}

/**
 * Handle the command.
 */
public function handle()
{
    $conversation = $this->message->conversation;
    $conversation->touch();
    if ($conversation->isGlobal())
    {
        Push::trigger($this->confer->global, 'NewMessageWasPosted', $this->message->getEventData('global'));
    } else {
        Push::trigger($this->message->conversation->getChannel(), 'NewMessageWasPosted', $this->message->getEventData());
        Push::trigger($this->message->conversation->getChannel(), 'UserStoppedTyping', ['user' => $this->message->sender->id]);
    }
}

}
```

```
namespace DJB\Confer\Events;

class MessageWasSent {

public function __construct()
{

}

public function handle()
{

}

}
```

Comment: please show us some code

Comment: You should not directly modify that package. It exposes the views to you if you do `php artisan vendor:publish` under `resources/views/vendor/confer/`

Comment: @Abhishek Added some, but the package coding itself isn't changed other than a few compatibility tweaks for Laravel 5.3

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I have done a vendor:publish, I didn't altar the views in the vendor file, just the ones published to my `/views` folder. Is that still not okay? I just can't find the view/code that controls the formatting of a new message.